# Flag test as expected to fail in unit 5

Tags: junit-jupiter

I have a unit test, written with JUnit 5 (Jupiter), that is failing.  I do not currently have time to fix the problem, so I would like to mark the test as an expected failure.  Is there a way to do that?

I see `@Disable` which causes the test to not be run.  I would like the test to still run (and ideally fail the build if it starts to work), so that I remember that the test is there.

Is there such an annotation in Junit 5?  I could use `assertThrows` to catch the error, but I would like the build output to indicate that this is not a totally normal test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the failing test with the `@Disabled` annotation. You can then add another test that asserts the first one does indeed fail:

```
@Test
@Disabled
void fixMe() {
    Assertions.fail();
}

@Test
void fixMeShouldFail() {
    assertThrows(AssertionError.class, this::fixMe);
}
```

Comment: Clunky, but it would work.  It's be nice if the API understood the concept, so that reports could indicate it in a separate category.

Answer (score 2):

The [JUnit Pioneer project](https://junit-pioneer.org/) provides an annotation for this exact use case: [@ExpectedToFail](https://junit-pioneer.org/docs/expected-to-fail-tests/)